# Dropdownlist select all while distinct

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdownlist that retrieve the values from the database.
The values are the month and the year of the date of user input. The dropdownlist example:-

- --Select Month--
- 11-2013
- 12-2013
- 03-2015
- 02-2016

I have done the query to get the result as above:-

`SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')) AS date
FROM tbl
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m')
ASC`

However, I'm quite confused on how to display all of other columns in `tbl` after selecting the month in the dropdownlist. Say, in the table `tbl`, there are `description` and `personInCharge` column aside the `date` column. When selecting the month in the dropdownlist, it suppose to retrieve all data that is related with the selected month.

I've tried using these:-

`SELECT *, DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')) AS date
FROM tbl
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m')
ASC`

and

`SELECT description, personInCharge, DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')) AS date
FROM tbl
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m')
ASC`

and such but all I get is error. Where am I wrong? How am I to complete this? Is it by using join clause? If so, how?

**--UPDATE--**

I get to list out the details by using this query:-

`SELECT *, (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y'))AS month FROM tbl`

But, I still don't know how to integrate with the dropdownlist.

Comment: If you select distinct dates you are going to leave out some descriptions/PIC. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Kuya #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')) AS date FROM tbl ORDER B' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just using these two queries. The first query is for dropdownlist. The second query is to display values from table.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y'))
                    AS month
                    FROM tbl
                    ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m')
                    ASC");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')) AS month
                                 FROM tbl
                                 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date),'%m-%Y')='$date'");
```

If theres any wrong with my code, lets discuss here.